# Postman (JavaScript) - How do I create environment variables based on how many objects are in a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I need to create a certain amount of environment variables that depend on the amount of objects in a JSON array. They variables need to be named differently, of course. I've tried the following but I can't seem to get the variables created.

```
var jsonstuff = JSON.parse(responseBody);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonstuff.bullets.length; i++){
    postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("Bullet" + (i+1));
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Bullet" + (i+1), jsonstuff.bullets[i]);
}
```

I'm brand new to Javascript, so any information, no matter how trivial, will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good to me... I mocked some data on my side and it worked fine when doing the following:

```js
var responseBody = {
  "bullets": [
    {
      "_id": "5a32c9b400bf7e499ca242f2",
      "index": 0,
      "guid": "69ad4f73-b355-4268-94ef-b92f6cab505b",
      "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a32c9b482a6a89661d98e85",
      "index": 1,
      "guid": "6c8a1628-3fa9-4b52-b8d3-5719cd3889f7",
      "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a32c9b4610f9bb923a01a28",
      "index": 2,
      "guid": "7084aa50-dc85-410c-8dbb-02f860c3d97a",
      "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a32c9b43c17b09d2e5d819e",
      "index": 3,
      "guid": "5d076aa8-af3a-4af1-bf49-e62ade7c3ed0",
      "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a32c9b48594eea1e008c190",
      "index": 4,
      "guid": "5d1f4bcb-0d59-4acc-af0a-4041a1aefb7f",
      "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
    }
  ]
};

//because my example is already an object, it does not need to be parsed into a javascript object
var jsonstuff = responseBody;

for (var i = 0; i < jsonstuff.bullets.length; i++){
    postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("Bullet" + (i+1));
    //this is the key change. without JSON.stringify(), the environment varible will be set to [Object object]
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Bullet" + (i+1), JSON.stringify(jsonstuff.bullets[i]));
}
```

NOTE: Without JSON.stringify, it was setting the environment vars to "[Object object]"

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked exactly as you said it would. Will keep the NOTE in mind for future endeavors.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you're on your way :)

Answer (score 1):

No real expert here either, but I always use `pm.environment.set( "... name ...", jsonData.someProperty);`. I have not tried the indexing that you are using.

Apart from that, there may be some errors in your code, you are missing `.length` and `var`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonstuff.bullets.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the errors that you pointed out. Ran it again, but still have the same problems. Your help is much appreciated!